# SwiftUI fails to build preview with compiling error

Tags: swiftui

When I go to view my SwiftUI through the canvas preview in Xcode 11.3.1 I am getting the error

```
Compiling failed: 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
```

But the project itself builds successfully and the simulator loads without any issues.  I have tried clearing the build folder, quitting Xcode and rebuilding but still no luck.

Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this SwiftUI only project? Which is deployment target version?

Comment: @Asperi No, the project also has files using UIKIt and the deployment target is 11.4.  Thanks

Comment: I don't get the question. If your deployment target is 11.4 but `Color` is only available in 13.0, then that's the issue. Just bump up the deployment target to 13.0, or don't use `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI minimum deployment target is 13.0, so if you have project with support of older version, then all SwiftUI code (including preview providers) you have to prepend with availability modifier, like

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)  // << here !!
struct Demo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I do already have @available(iOS 13.0, *) , so the project does compile fine it's just the preview part.  I did change the target to IOS 13.2 but now I am getting the error 'Compiling for iOS 11.4, but module [appName] has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.2' but I have checked the swift compile version and It's 5. Any ideas please?

Comment: @user2047296, would you provide some demo code to reproduce?

Comment: The problem is the project is compiling fine, it's just the preview that is causing issues due to the 'Compiling for iOS 11.4...' error, I changed the deployment target for the pods project but am still encountering issues.  Have you came across this issue before?

Comment: I ended up solving the issue... I was only changing the deployment target for the target and not the project.  When I changed the target for the project it fixed the issue I was having.  @Asperi Thank you for your help and everything! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Man, I've had a similar issue. The problem was that sometimes my preview worked sometimes it didn't... I reviewed the diagnostics and realized that there are some `@_dynamicReplacement` attributes mentioned (which are used, I guess, for hot reloading). It wasn't working when I've had a file with **`@available`** attributes opened in the (adjacent) editor. **When I closed that editor everything worked back again.**

Magic ✨

Also one more hint from my friend - when you have a file from another target (not the one hosting your Canvas-related code) in (adjacent) editor it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Assets or Other option like *Color Literal* for **Color**.
Don't use the system **Color** option since your deployment target is 11.4.